# Get JSON Google Directions Output in another Language?

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm using JSON output of Google Directions to parse it in my Android App, is there a way to retrieve the Directions using another language? in KML I used to add this parameter hl=xx for another language Directions but I tried this out on JSON and it doesn't effect (still get english Directions). There is region parameter but I didn't understand how to use it, is this the solution (to use region parameter)? Any ideas?

This is an example link: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/json?hl=fr&origin=26.2,50.6&destination=26.3,50.7&sensor=true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add `language` parameter in the url as shown below:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=26.2,50.6&destination=26.3,50.7&sensor=true&language=cs

Comment: Thanks, thats not mentioned in Google [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON)

Comment: No problem.  If this solves your issue just accept the answer so other people don't keep trying to answer it for you :)

Comment: I will, it says you need to wait 10 mins to accept an answer :(